# N1QL prepared statement not working 100%

Tags: php, prepared-statement, couchbase, sql++

I have a problem where some variables are probably (I can't know for sure) not inserted into the final statement. Here is my example:

**Works:**

```
public static function findByPageAndFieldContains($recordsPerPage, $page, $field, $searchterm) {
    $query = CouchbaseN1qlQuery::fromString('SELECT * FROM `public_portal` WHERE `collection`=$collection AND TOSTRING('.$field.') LIKE "%'.$searchterm.'%" ORDER BY `_id` limit $limit offset $offset');
    $query->options['$collection'] = static::COLLECTION_NAME;
    //$query->options['$field'] = $field;
    $query->options['$limit'] = $recordsPerPage;
    $query->options['$offset'] = $recordsPerPage*($page-1);
    //$query->options['$searchterm'] = $searchterm;

    $result = DB::getDB()->query($query);
    var_dump($query);
    var_dump($result);
    $objects = array();
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $object = new static($row->{"public_portal"});
        $object->setId($row->{"public_portal"}->{"_id"});
        $objects[] = $object;
    }
    //var_dump($objects);
    return $objects;
    return $result;
}
```

Debug Output:
[debug01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfSMl.png)

**Does not work:**

```
public static function findByPageAndFieldContains($recordsPerPage, $page, $field, $searchterm) {
    $query = CouchbaseN1qlQuery::fromString('SELECT * FROM `public_portal` WHERE `collection`=$collection AND TOSTRING($field) LIKE "%$searchterm%" ORDER BY `_id` limit $limit offset $offset');
    $query->options['$collection'] = static::COLLECTION_NAME;
    $query->options['$field'] = $field;
    $query->options['$limit'] = $recordsPerPage;
    $query->options['$offset'] = $recordsPerPage*($page-1);
    $query->options['$searchterm'] = $searchterm;

    $result = DB::getDB()->query($query);
    var_dump($query);
    var_dump($result);
    $objects = array();
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $object = new static($row->{"public_portal"});
        $object->setId($row->{"public_portal"}->{"_id"});
        $objects[] = $object;
    }
    //var_dump($objects);
    return $objects;
    return $result;
}
```

Debug output:
[debug02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbJeE.png)

Basically the second example returns no result, while the first one works just fine.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using N1QL parameters correctly. You must decide if you are evaluating your parameters in PHP or in N1QL.

The field name cannot be a N1QL parameter, so you evaluate it in PHP:

```
TOSTRING('.$field.') LIKE ...
```

The search term should be a N1QL parameter, so you add wildcards in PHP and then pass it to N1QL as a parameter:

```
$searchterm = '%'.$searchterm.'%'

TOSTRING('.$field.') LIKE $searchterm ...
```

Comment: Ok, $searchterm works now. Thanks. But for the $field, is removing ";" and using addslashes() on it enough or is there a special function for couchbase like there is for other RDBMS?

Comment: like this: $field = addslashes(str_replace(";", "", $field));

Comment: I just realized you can't escape characters with ` \ ` so no `addslashes()`. ATM I'm using `$field = str_replace([";", "'", '"', "´", "\`"], "", $field);` Is this a good solution or do you know a better solution?

Comment: That is a PHP question, not a N1QL question, so I can't speak to that. Just remember that N1QL does not see $field. It must be pre-processed in your PHP and sent to N1QL non-parametrized.